# Изменение записей в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, form, redbeanphp

Совсем не давно начал изучать PHP, у меня была задача, сделать авторизацию на сайте, с горем но мне удалось это сделать с помощью **RedBeanPHP**. Теперь стоит задача, сделать поле в котором я могу например поменять у пользователя его Никнейм. Как это реализовать?

[image: То, что я пытался сделать]

Если есть возможность помогине с полным написанием кода для изменения имени пользователя

С этим кодом он выдает ошибку **HTTP ERROR 500**

Comment: Где ` ?>` после пятой строки.  и зачем там вообще это.
Вы даже не осознаете, что вы пишите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения этого вопроса вам нужно сделать несколько вещей:
 1. Запросить в базе всех пользователей в виде массива. Вывести с помощью цикла их никнеймы (исходя из вашего ТЗ) в виде

```
<? 
echo'
    <input type="text" name="nickName" id="nickName" value="'.$row['nickName'].'">
    <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Сменить имя">
';
?>
```

2. Далее нам надо, что бы при нажатии на кнопку данные передавались в скрипт, и данные записывались в базу. Т.е. надо сделать `UPDATE` в базе для определенной записи.
   Итого. Нам для успешной записи надо иметь - id_идентификатор пользователя в базе, его новое имя(поле nickName).
   Подумайте, как это сделать.

Можно добавить к вашему коду немного JS. Это позволит не плодить кучу форм, а использовать только input'ы.
Либо для каждого пользователя плодить форму при обработке массива.

Это так. в общих чертах если. Всегда можно сделать лучше.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100997/discussion-on-answer-by-------).